# Why duplicate symbol commands

Tags: symbols

I am wondering why so many duplicates of a symbol exist in latex. Let me provide some:
For prime I know two types: 1. `$f'$` 2. `$f^\prime$`
in [Wiki Prime Symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29) it is explained why `\prime` is introduced:

"LaTeX provides an oversized prime symbol, `\prime` for use in subscripts [for example `$f_\prime$`]"

Yet I wonder why an oversized symbol? Or the backslash: 1. `\backslash` 2. `\setminus` what is the difference? For a long list of slashes in latex visit [unicode slashes](http://groups.google.com/group/unimath/browse_thread/thread/56fb1bbf8c94989d). I can't understand why so many duplicates and if I don't know the difference, maybe I use it in wrong place. BTW I don't mean the characters that have minor differences (like `\nu` and `\upsilon` which look nearly the same).

How can I make sure I am using the correct symbol despite the similar look?
What is the real difference between them?

Comment: @Yasser, according to the moderator here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/is-there-a-latex-distribution-running-on-ipad >Please don't use quote (>) markup for emphasis. That's not what it's for.

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't know that. Is it for highlighting the question? Is the new format OK?

Comment: @Yasser, I think the quote markup is created to enclose text quoted from other sources. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your advice :D. FYI, in the brotherhood of this forum (cstheory.stackexchange.com) we nearly always use such a mechanism to highlight the question :D. This is more like highlighting rather than quoting. Any way, I give up using it :-).

Comment: @xport, Yasser: Must admit, that's a habit I got into as well from MathOverflow.  I like being able to highlight the actual question in amongst all the background and motivation.  If anyone has any better ideas how to achieve the same end, say so at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/812/emphasising-the-actual-question

Comment: Regarding `\backslash`/`\setminus`, from TeXbook: "It’s customary to say `$G\backslash H$` to denote double cosets of G by H (G\H), and `$p\backslash n$` to mean that p divides n (p\n); but `$X\setminus Y$` denotes the elements of set X minus those of set Y (X \ Y). Both operations use the same symbol, but `\backslash` is type **Ord**, while `\setminus` is type **Bin** (so TEX puts more space around it)."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For many symbols it’s just that the purpose is different. Consider the set minus: what you want there **isn’t** a backslash. You really want a “set minus” – which just happens to be displayed (sometimes) identically to a backslash. But it’s still fundamentally different.

Now, which of the two LaTeX codes is more readable:

```
\mathcal{F} \backslash \{ 0 \}
% or
\mathcal{F} \setminus \{ 0 \}
```

If the two are really identical (which I don’t believe since as Carsten points out there’s always the issue of spacing in math mode) one can simply be defined in terms of the other – e.g.:

```
\newcommand*\setminus{\backslash}
```

No harm in that. This still makes the usage more readable (see above) and the macro can be exchanged very quickly if you decide that the symbol should be displayed differently. For example, consider that the set minus is actually often written like a normal minus instead of like a backslash. If you have used the `\backslash` command, you now need to change all occurrences of that in your document.

If you have used a dedicated command then you only need to redefine that:

```
\newcommand*\setminus{\ensuremath{{}-{}}}
```

In practice, I redefine aliases for almost all macros that I use to fit my current use-case.

Answer (score 14):

The reason why `\prime` is "oversized" is so that, when it occurs in a superscript, it will appear to be the "right" size.

Most of the time, you would not really need to explicitly refer to the `\prime` macro; you would just use `'`. And indeed, in ten years of LaTeX coding, I used `\prime` for the first time only just recently — in a superscript, even — but in a way that I couldn't possibly achieve with `'` alone: in the code `f^{\prime\prime\cdots\prime}`.

Comment: Wow, very nice!  It's the first time I see *real* use for `\prime`!

Comment: An even better usage (but one which I avoid for aesthetic reasons): `a^{\prime\;-1}`, for when you want to take the inverse of a primed variable.

Answer (score 13):

The prime `'` and the control sequence `\prime` are in fact quite different beasts. The former is defined in terms of the latter: The `\mathcode` of `'` is `"8000`, which makes it an active character in math mode. It is defined to be a macro that is clever enough so that `'` expands to `^{\prime}`, `''` expands to `^{\prime\prime}`,`'''` expands to `^{\prime\prime\prime}`, and so forth. This is necessary because multiple exponents aren't allowed.

Answer (score 9):

Very often what seems as duplicates have some (more or less) subtle differences regarding size and spaces.

Concerning your examples, you will see the difference in spacing for `\backslash` and `\setminus` and in the size for `\prime` and `'`. Which one you would use in what case is probably an entirely different question.

```
\[ A\backslash B\quad A\setminus B \qquad  b_{'}\quad b_\prime\]
```