# App to Add photos to LaTex document with iPad camera?

Tags: distributions, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a (La)TeX distribution running on iPad?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/is-there-a-latex-distribution-running-on-ipad)

Very simple app that I am trying to find: suppose I have written a long text in my Laptop in LaTex but missing images. I am lazy student and I want to just photograph the photos to the document and insert them fast to it. Does there exist some LaTex image-insertion app?

**Perhaps related**

> 1. iPad question to read textbooks and write in Math SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/204393#204393)
> 2. [Is there a (La)TeX distribution running on iPad?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/is-there-a-latex-distribution-running-on-ipad) and  [Now that I can run TeX on my iPad, what shall I TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68436/now-that-i-can-run-tex-on-my-ipad-what-shall-i-tex)
> 3. Image-manipulation question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65768/image-manipulation-app-with-ipad-that-gets-images-directly-from-its-camera-and)

Comment: ...sorry for proposing closing, I refocused this question now thanks to the feedback. It is not anymore dupe. This request was in my original q.

Comment: Actually, this is possible in the TeX Writer app, providing your document compiles with it (as it doesn't yet support some of the later additions to TeX).

Comment: Step 1: Take photo in usual iPad way.  Step 2: Upload to the TeX Writer Dropbox folder using Dropbox.  Step 3: from within TeX Writer, click on the photo and adjust the size as needed.  Step 4: click the "copy and paste" button to write the `\includegraphics` into your LaTeX document.

Comment: Go to the file list and select the photo from there.

Comment: @AndrewStacey roger but it is not really what I wanted with iPad-direct-insertion, more in my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74678/2956).

Comment: This is turning into a question more about iPad apps than about TeX and so is in danger of getting off-topic.  Indeed, a version of this has now been asked on the apple site.

Comment: You can use the online LaTeX editor [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com) to easily add photos to a LaTeX document: capturing a photo is an option on the upload file menu when writeLaTeX is used on an iPad.

Comment: [Note re the above comment - I am one of the developers at writeLaTeX, I should have made that clear, sorry]

Comment: @JohnHammersley use Jquery-uploader Dropzone code to create such `"easily add photos to a Latex document"`. Your thing is a previewer -- if you could add it Apple OS X-style-Dropzone functionality, it may become useful -- not sure yet (uploading photo required clicking many things and then showing it required to remember an one-liner). Please, add DropZone and format detection to do it really `"easily"` -- hope you success! [Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) but make it simpler. I may be able to help with it if you cannot get it done.

Comment: @hhh thanks for the suggestion, will look into it and let you know how we get on. The feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Might want to look into TexPad (9 USD), not sure about directly sharing, but it has dropbox synced up, so you could at least share from dropbox.

Comment: do you know whether you can photograph and then embed that photo straight away to the LaTex document? I had to refocus my question, this feature is something I am really wanting to get: photograph and add fast photos to your LaTex document with iPad. I have laptop to write things fast but adding pictures is a pain.

Comment: Texpad developers here. You can import images from the photo library or from the camera itself into Texpad. Please see the link for full details: http://support.texpadapp.com/kb/user-interface-ios/graphics-support-in-texpad-ios-and-os-x

Comment: @VVTexpad yes and please add some Apple style such as wipe-over-removal tool, press-your-finger-for-a-while-multifunction-tool (with fast addition of pictures, fast moving of files/dirs), autocompletion missing for common commands, local typesetting bugged with relative paths such as images ./Pictures/hello.png not working while Pictures/hello.png working, local typesetting not showing the mistakes with the relative path problem but cloud typesetting shows them -- real artists ship. You are getting better but you still need to go to the goal. Less is more, less typing more thinking.