# Texlive on IOS for ipad

Tags: texlive, ipad

It is preferred to use ipad to create and edit TeX files and use LaTeX. I know some applications to use TeX but they need Internet and are not complete. Is it possible to use texlive on Ipad (IOS)?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/is-there-a-latex-distribution-running-on-ipad

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".