# How to Read/Edit tex files on an Ipad

Tags: best-practices

I use LaTeX for writing books. I would like to extend my working environment and, I was wondering if it is possible to read (or much better - edit) tex files containing text only on an ipad? I know that there are a few LaTeX editors for the ipad out there. But, I use Aquamacs as my main writing editor and, LuaLaTeX as the writing medium. I do not want the file format changed in any way. Does anyone have any ideas? I thought of using say, Dropbox and then being able to open the file on the ipad, add a sentence or two, correct a few spelling errors say then, send the file back to Dropbox. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you just want to edit the  `tex`  files, or do you want to compile them as well? Every text editor can read write plain text.

Comment: Johannes_B: No, I don't want to compile them. I want to make simple edits, save, then send them back to Aquamacs on my desktop for compiling later.

Comment: So the answer to your question is: Every text editor can read and edit text files, `vi`, `emacs`, `notepad`, `notepad++` etc... The question how to setup a dropbox (or maybe a github repository) seems to be off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

From top of my head I can mention few apps([1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tex-writer-latex-editor-compiler/id552717222), [2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/texpad-latex-editor/id550419159), [3](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/verbtex-latex-editor/id560869163)). I think all of these apps have Dropbox integration for syncing. Some allow you to compile your document on the device, some using internet servers and some, are just editors.

But perhaps, you can have better answers looking at this [Q/A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/is-there-a-latex-distribution-running-on-ipad) in this very website.