# Compile and Edit (La)TeX on iPad-pro 2020

Tags: pdftex, mac, overleaf, distributions, ipad

As an academic writer using (La)TeX to write documents, there is always a question we had for iPad...

Can the newest generation [iPad-pro 2020](https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/) run LaTex such as TexShop or other (La)TeX software that you use on MacBook (Pro)? and then produce a PDFTeX?

1. If yes, please provide how to do it.
2. If not, what are the other resolutions to use/compile (La)TeX?

What comes into my mind:

- [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/): run LaTex online. (This answer does not exist in 2010.)
- other lists from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors

I suppose the [iPad-pro 2020](https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/) may make new differences for us to run (La)TeX on iPad?

(p.s. There was a prior question in 2010 but now we are in 2020, the answer was 10 years ago:
[Is there a (La)TeX distribution running on iPad?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8021/41144))

Comment: I don't really think there's too much to add to the existing question. A quick look at the App Store finds TeXPad still around, and a few others TeX Writer, Verb TeX (which seems to require online compilation) and LaTeX Editor Pro. I have no experience with any of them, as I have never found the need to use my iPad in this way.

Comment: My point is that suppose we do not have a laptop or desktop. Suppose we only have iPAD to work for LaTex documents -- is this convenient and doable? Thanks!

Comment: My point was that other than a search of the App Store, there's not much difference between your question and the one you link to. Recommendations for specific apps is off topic. It's clearly doable, and convenience is purely opinion based.  Also if you look at the answers in the linked question, there are two still existing iPad apps mentioned, and WriteLaTeX (which is now Overleaf).

Comment: I see, WriteLaTeX is now Overleaf!?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but worth knowing: Instead of iOS, if you have an Android-based tablet, you can install a free app that provides Linux Terminal, then install TeXlive and a virtual network server, and see the graphics via another app. No root needed, does not need to be online except when downloading. Widely used, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use texpad. Is designed for both iOS and macOS:

https://www.texpad.com/ios

Comment: That’s really expensive for what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the free app "a-Shell" for this purpose (and many others).

https://apps.apple.com/de/app/a-shell/id1473805438

a-Shell is a local terminal emulator, including TeX (texlive 2022, with Tikz and LuaTeX) for text processing.

For editing the tex-files you can use vim (also included in a-Shell) or any other editor like Koder (https://apps.apple.com/de/app/koder-code-editor/id1447489375)

In a-Shell just type "pdflatex file.tex" and after that "view file.pdf".

Or view the created pdf in "Documents" with live-updates after compiling (https://apps.apple.com/de/app/documents-file-manager-app/id364901807).

A good point to start with a-Shell is:
https://github.com/holzschu/a-shell

Answer (score 2):

I have just developed and published HoLaTeX in the App Store. HoLaTeX is a port of Texlive 2023 to iOS and iPadOS.
The app is available at https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/holatex/id6458879810 .
HoLaTeX is easy to use and compiles the tex files without internet connection.
This is the first version of the app, don't hesitate to share your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

My friends and I developed TeXable for iPadOS. You can find it in the App Store. You can also visit https://texable.io for more info. TeXable can compile tex files with no internet connection, and has a few useful features such as figure inserter, table generation, matrix maker, etc to make writing tex documents a bit more convenient.

Comment: Hello, I cannot get Texable to open on an M1 iPad running IOS 16.3. As soon as I click the icon to open it, it shows a blank screen momentarily and shuts down immediately. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.