# Is there a ConTeΧt text editor and compiler on ipad? Do TeΧ editors work for ConTeΧt?

Tags: context, mac, ipad

Is there a way to write in ConTeΧt on ipad and compile it (see a pdf preview of the code)?

- It’s not ok to use just a text editor, because it doesn’t give you the preview.
- I found some apps that let you write in LaTeΧ or TeΧ and have a pdf preview, but are they also good for ConTeΧt, or is it a different thing? (for example see https://apps.apple.com/it/app/tex-writer-latex-on-the-go/id552717222).
- An online/web-based editor and compiler would be okay too, if I can use it from ipad, as long as i can save the file somewhere (google drive, or the “files” app on ipad).

On the ConTeΧt documentation I didn’t find anything useful.
Note that I never used LaTeΧ, ConTeΧt or any TeΧ language before and I know very little about them, so sorry for eventual misunderstandings or misconceptions.

Also, using something else instead of ConTeΧt is not an alternative possible way.

Finally, I know that [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/is-there-a-latex-distribution-running-on-ipad) exists, but it seems pretty old and asks about LaTeΧ or TeΧ distributions on iPad, not ConTeΧt.

Comment: I don't have an IPad to test but I think the Texpad iOS app offers ConTeXt support through the 'cloud typesetter' option (note the `t` at the end of ConTeXt). In any case it supports LaTeX so you could just use that - it is maybe a bit less clean than ConTeXt but it is very usable once you get to know it, and the ecosystem is much larger than for ConTeXt.

Comment: @Marijn thank you, but since it costs 25€, i don’t think i’ll buy it just to see if it works. Maybe i’ll try to write to the developers and see if they can give me a sure answer

Comment: [KeenWrite](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite#download) offers a live preview of a document while editing, which will be a rough representation of the final output. I tend to have [Evince](https://ports.macports.org/port/evince/) open at the same time. When I want to compile the document, I press `Ctrl+P` in KeenWrite to export to PDF. After ConTeXt finishes typesetting the document using a specific [theme](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes), Evince reloads the new version automatically.